# reverse() usage in python?

Tags: python, reverse

> The sort() and reverse() methods modify the list in place for economy of space when sorting or reversing a large list. To remind you that they operate by side effect, they don’t return the sorted or reversed list.

The above text can be found at http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#mutable-sequence-types

What does "modify the list in place for economy of space" mean?

Example:

```
x = ["happy", "sad"]
y = x.reverse()
```

would return `None` to `y`. So then why does,

```
x.reverse()
```

Successfully reverse `x`?

Answer (score 7):

> What does "modify the list in place for economy of space" mean?

What this means is that it does not create a copy of the list.

> why does, x.reverse() Successfully reverse x?

I don't understand this question. It does this because that's what it's designed to do (reverse `x` and return `None`).

Note that `sort()` and `reverse()` have counterparts that don't modify the original and return a copy. These functions are called [`sorted()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#sorted) and [`reversed()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#reversed):

```
In [7]: x = [1, 2, 3]

In [8]: y = list(reversed(x))

In [9]: x
Out[9]: [1, 2, 3]

In [10]: y
Out[10]: [3, 2, 1]
```

Comment: I guess the OP wonders how it's possible to reverse a list in-place.

Comment: sorry about that shouldve been more clear, my question is why would  `x.reverse(), print(x)` print `x` reversed instead of `None`?

Comment: @user3316430: `print(x)` prints the value of `x`, which is the original list reversed.

Answer (score 3):

`list.reverse` reverses the list in-place and returns `None`, it's designed to do so, similar to `append`, `remove`, `extend`, `insert`, etc.

```
In [771]: x = ["happy", "sad"]

In [772]: x.reverse()

In [773]: x
Out[773]: ['sad', 'happy']
```

Answer (score 1):

In almost any programming language there are two kinds of *callable definitions*: functions and procedures.

Functions are methods or subroutines that do some processing and return a value. For instance, a function to sum two integers `a` and `b` will return the result of the sum `a + b`.

In the other hand, procedures are pretty much the same (even in the syntax in most languages) with the slight difference that don't return a value, and of course they are used by their *side effects*, meaning that they change the state of something or just process some data and save it or just print it out to a file.

So in this case, `reverse` would act as a procedure, which changes the state of the list being reversed (by reversing it), and here is how this can be done without extra space:

```
def reverse(l):
    for i in range(len(l) / 2):
        l[i], l[-i-1] = l[-i-1], l[i]
```

Notice that a new list is never created, instead, what the code does is to interchange the elements of the list `l` *in place* by swapping the first and the last, the second and the penultimate and so on until the element in the half of the list.

Hope this helps you understand ;)